# How to read deep JSON data using Vuejs and Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

How would I read deep JSON data nested deep inside a file? I've tried different methods and can't seem to get this to work.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="edu in info" :key="edu">

            <div>{{ edu.section.title }}</div> // this is what im trying to get to work
        </div>

        <div class="card container">
            {{ info }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                info: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get('./calculus.json') // Data Below
                .then(response => (this.info = response.data.edu))
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
</script>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```json
{
    "edu": {
        "1": {
            "title": "Title One",
            "subtitle": "Subtitle One",
            "description": "Description One",
            "section": {
                "1": {
                    "title": "Section One Title",
                    "content": "Section One Content"
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "title": "Title Two",
            "subtitle": "Subtitle Two",
            "description": "Description Two",
            "section": {
                "1": {
                    "title": "Section One Title",
                    "content": "Section One Content"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use vue-for and get the data inside the section to get it to display under the title? For example: title, section>title, section>subtitle, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given each `section` is also an object with weird numeric keys, you can iterate them in the same way you do `info`.

I would also advise you to use identifiable values instead of the entire `edu` object in your `:key` bindings.

```html
<div v-for="(edu, eduId) in info" :key="eduId">
  <div v-for="(section, sectionId) in edu.section" :key="sectionId">
    {{ section.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If possible, I would alter the format of your JSON data to use actual arrays instead of objects with numeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

One way to browse your object deeply is to cumulate v-for on your object (and children) entries.

ie:

```html
<div v-for="([category, books], catkey) in Object.entries(info)" :key="`category-${catkey}`">
    <div>{{ category }} :</div>
    <div v-for="([num, book], numkey) in Object.entries(books)" :key=`book-${catkey}-${numkey}`>
        <div v-for="([field, value], valkey) in Object.entries(book)" :key=`field-${catkey}-${numkey}-${valkey}`>
            {{ field }} : {{ value }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you find it too verbose, you may try to **flatten** your computed data to have the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "category": "edu",
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Title One",
        "subtitle": "Subtitle One",
        "description": "Description One",
        "section": {
            "1": {
                "title": "Section One Title",
                "content": "Section One Content"
            }
        }
    }
]
```